# Why would we su without -?

Tags: su

When we do `su John` I switch as user John.
When we do `su - John` I switch as user John having user John's environment.
As far as I can see the first option is useless. What is the use of switching to another user and not have that user's environment?
Am I wrong? What is the difference in use cases between these 2 options?

Comment: This is not a dupe, the OP is asking what a legitimate use case for `su user` would be. Why wouldn't one want to use `su - user` instead. Not what the difference between the two is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**su John**

if you use `su John` only then basically you just temporary "borrow" the `John` permission without having all the `John` environment setting. You will notice that you are not having sbin path. Which means some `John` commands you issue at this environment might not work.

**su - John**

when you use `su - John` command, you are given a new login shell from the Linux server, which is the same as you logout from the existing user and perform a fresh login.

Comment: My question is why do we even need `su John` not what is the difference."...only then basically you just temporary "borrow" the John permission without having all the John environment setting" This seems useless to me

Comment: This explains the concept, but does not answer the question.